# Access local machines from Virtualbox VM on VPN

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn, nat

I have a Virtualbox VM running under Windows 7, and connected to a remote VPN through a software called "Check Point". This VPN connection is required to retrieve data from a remote database.

Now, I would like to send the retrieved data to a server in my local network.
The problem is that while connected to the VPN, my VM cannot of course find this local server (and I have absolutely no possibility to change anything in the VPN).

One solution that I tried was to define a second network interface on my VM, in NAT mode, and redirect traffic from 127.0.0.1 on port 2222 to the IP of my local server on port 22 (for instance), but could not manage to make it work.

Is this solution possible, or do you have any other idea how to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get this right, you have a local network using the same address prefix as the one defined by your VPN provider.

In this case, you have to delete the conflicting routes set up by CheckPoint and replace them with a more precise mask (deleting a 10.0.0.0/8 then add 10.128.0.0/9).

Do this in the Windows VM conencted to the VPN using the ROUTE command.

```
ROUTE DELETE 10.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 IF <vpn_iterface_number>
ROUTE ADD 10.0.0.0 MASK 255.128.0.0 IF <vpn_iterface_number>
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!